# Helm Conditional resource creation if installing on Openshift

Tags: openshift, kubernetes-helm, helm3, security-context

I am trying to create a Helm chart conditional template for a `SecurityContextConstraint` / SCC based whether I'm installing on an Openshift cluster or not. Because SCCs are Openshift-specific resources.

So that, on executing `helm install <release-name> <chart> -n <namespace>`) on an Openshift cluster, SCC should automatically get created.

Fallback option would be to use something like this:

```yaml
{{ if .Values.isOpenshift }}
apiVersion: security.openshift.io/v1
kind: SecurityContextConstraints
...
{{ end }}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Helm's [Built-in Objects](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/) include a `.Capabilities` object that can be used to inspect the cluster, and more specifically, check whether a specific API version or resource type is supported.  Call `.Capabilities.APIVersions.Has` with the `apiVersion` or `apiVersion/kind` field(s) you want to check.

```yaml
{{- if .Capabilities.APIVersions.Has "security.openshift.io/v1/SecurityContextConstraints" }}
apiVersion: security.openshift.io/v1
kind: SecurityContextConstraints
...
{{- end }}
```

Comment: This worked with a small fix: I used `.Capabilities.APIVersions.Has`

Comment: You're absolutely right, I've fixed the answer.